# Posting "0" to Slack channel via `slacker` and Slack API

Tags: python, slack-api, slack

I am trying to automatically post some numbers to my slack channel via the `slacker` package (version 0.8.6). Sometimes the number that needs to be printed is a `0`, but I've found that posting `0` or `"0"` gives me an error...

```
from slacker import Slacker
API_TOKEN = XXXXXXXXXX # I load in my api token from an environment variable
slack = Slacker(API_TOKEN)
channel = '#test-channel'
message = "0"
slack.chat.post_message(channel, message, parse='full')
```

I get this error: `slacker.Error: no_text`

Is this a bug in my code, `slacker`, or the Slack API itself?

Full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "field-utils/fieldutils/slack.py", line 56, in <module>
    slack.chat.post_message(channel, message, parse='full')
  File "/Users/pedro/tools/slack-bot/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/slacker/__init__.py", line 257, in post_message
    'icon_emoji': icon_emoji
  File "/Users/pedro/tools/slack-bot/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/slacker/__init__.py", line 69, in post
    return self._request(requests.post, api, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/pedro/tools/slack-bot/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/slacker/__init__.py", line 61, in _request
    raise Error(response.error)
slacker.Error: no_text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your problem. I'm looking at [Slacker](https://github.com/os/slacker/tree/e71314e166c2b64928d3871133339af5ddb0ddd8) and it [seems like the Slack API is returning the error](https://github.com/os/slacker/blob/e71314e166c2b64928d3871133339af5ddb0ddd8/slacker/__init__.py#L61) with that message.

try: `message = '0\n'` (It's a silly hack! But nothing else worked)

the Slack Desktop App seems to render it as if you'd sent `0`